# Friend-selector doesn't work?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created a very simple app to invite friends.

This is my code:

```
function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
FB.ui({
  method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'You should learn more about this awesome game.'
});
}
```

The friends selector appears but it doesn't work :(

**Live demo** and complete source code:

http://bit.ly/K4uyeJ

Comment: I added the app and the selector looked alright when opening, I'm obviously not about to try it for real and invite friends to use your test app, so maybe you can elaborate a bit about the "doesn't work" part? You get any errors?

Comment: yeah, when I send invites then the selector dissapears but no invite is sent ( I have 2 profile on facebook to test it ). I have used this script: http://www.fbrell.com/fb.ui/apprequests and it does work but my script doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code works fine for me.

Jumping slightly ahead and guessing a little; when you say it doesn't work, are you referring to a case where the recipients don't see the request?

If so, it's possible you haven't configured a Canvas App (i.e a way to access your app via apps.facebook.com/something ) - requests are only valid for mobile or canvas apps and are hidden otherwise.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/ for more information:

> User to User Requests are only available for Canvas apps, not
>   websites, as accepting a request will direct the user to the Canvas
>   Page URL of the app that sent the Request.

Comment: yep, the recipients don't see the request and I haven't a Canvas App. But in the past I have seen websites that send invites without a Canvas App.

Comment: That's not supported; any such websites were using the old pre-2010 requests, or had a canvas app which redirected back to their website (which is against policy)
It's also supported for mobile apps